# Bad flag in substitute command: 'i'.sql

Tags: php, phing

Running a database migrate in PHP (via Phing), I'm getting the following `FAILED BUILD` error:

```
Unable to open /site/thewebsite.co.uk/data/migrate-web_site-sed: 1:   "s/[^a-z0-9]/-/gi": bad flag in substitute command: 'i'.sql for reading:
```

as well as several warnings along similar lines:

```
[PHP Error] fopen(/site/thewebsite.co.uk/data/migrate-web_site-sed 1: "s/[^a-z0-9]/-/gi": bad flag in substitute command: 'i'.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [line 224 of /site/thewebsite.co.uk/vendor/phing/phing/classes/phing/tasks/ext/dbdeploy/DbDeployTask.php]
```

Does anyone have ideas about where to start looking for a resolution and/or the cause of the problem? The site files were cloned from a previously working repository and to my knowledge the DbDeployTask.php file has not been changed by any of my co-workers since the last working copy was cloned. I've had a look through the relevant .php file and I can't see any obvious issues. The section of the code referenced looks pretty standard:

```
protected function createOutputFile($file, $undo = false)
{
    $fileHandle = fopen($file, "w+");
    $sql = $this->generateSql($undo);
    fwrite($fileHandle, $sql);
}
```

With createOutputFile called from within the deploy function:

```
protected function deploy()
{
    // create deploy outputfile
    $this->createOutputFile($this->outputFile, false);

    // create undo deploy outputfile
    $this->createOutputFile($this->undoOutputFile, true);
}
```

Where would people advise looking for the source of this issue, so our Apache server is able to deploy the development website correctly on this Macintosh?

Comment: You should rather delete the whole question then. (Be aware, users with more reputation can still see the original question content in edit history.)

Comment: I want to note that the question has been removed and why. I will raise the issue in Meta if you like but I felt it appropriate to record management wishes in this instance.

Comment: The Barbra Streisand effect in action

Comment: I don't understand. What's the Barbara Steisand effect?

Comment: Is this something to do with the epic battles between Barbra Streisand and Robert Smith at all?

Comment: _“but I felt it appropriate to record management wishes in this instance”_ – that doesn’t provide any real value to future readers of this question (however they might stumble upon the link.) And, again – if the cause of your managment’s request was that the post included sensitive information: That __is__ still visible to a lot of people here.

Comment: The reason given was that a formal request was not made to post on StackOverflow before the posts were made. I have been told to continue to ask the web-team themselves and not to enlist outside help anymore.

Comment: It was noted that no-one on the site was able to help with any of the questions. Perhaps my work was seen as a waste of time, I don't know.

Comment: Are you unable to delete the question entirely? If so, flag for moderator attention. Leaving this as is doesn't help anyone.

Comment: It certainly doesn't help me.

Comment: This question is not receiving enough attention but I only have 500 rep and it needs at least 500 to solve...